What size wire for a 40A subpanel at 90 feet?
I want to run 40amp service to my garage that is 90’ from my house panel.
No welders or heavy draw, just a few lights and plugs and occasional power tool.
I have 1” voc piper buried across the driveway approx 40’ and then another line I need tan to the house and panel. I am told 8/3 and or 10/3 wire is fine.

There are several other questions that cover this too. You need a load calculation for your main panel to make sure you have capacity there, then subpanel in your garage can be any size (more spaces is better).

Yeah, run #2 aluminum, it's proven safe and is at a price/availability/performance sweet spot.   It's also cheaper than #8 copper and is 90A.
